# Find element of an array those have only specific character set using preg_grep() in php

Tags: php, arrays, preg-grep

I need to find only those elements of an array that have specific set of letters and any character before or after of finds word using PHP preg_grep() from array.

I have an array like following
`$findgroup = array("sten", "netff", "enet", "denet");`

I need to find the values from the array which have `'e,n,t'` characters and single or double character before or after(either side, not both side) the match word. If i search with pattern `e,n,t` and 1 letter before or after(either side, not both side) it the result will be `array("sten", "enet")` and if i search with pattern `e,n,t` and 2 letter before or after(either side, not both side) it the result will be 
`array("netff", "denet")` I tried with the following code but not works.

1 letter before or after(either side, not both side):

`$result = preg_grep("/^(?:.{1}".$value."|".$value.".{1})$/", $findgroup);`

2 letter before or after(either side, not both side):

`$result = preg_grep("/^(?:.{2}".$value."|".$value.".{2})$/", $findgroup);`

Here `$value` is my search pattern array i.e., `array('e', 'n', 't')`

Comment: @Toto i have see the link u add tried with it and its not work for me. I need preg_grep expression that search those array elemets that contains charcter from specific set with any order, but your given link solution work with fixed order pattern i.e., 'php'

Comment: I was just about to type in my answer!  (not a regex one)

Comment: @Toto that question is looking for literally ordered `php` this question is looking for `ent` or `net` or `ten` etc.

Comment: Why is the variable name identical in the other question?  Is this homework or something?

Comment: If you ask a new question seeking the same fitlered output but NOT using regex/preg_grep, then I have produced an answer for you.  ...what an irritating closure.

Comment: its just co-incident, of same variable name and its not a part of home work is a part of live job. currently i try to develop a word scrabble program

Comment: Is a non-regex solution okay for you?  I tried to write a regex pattern, but it was all getting to convoluted.  Will you ask a new question not requiring regex?  I'll have to find the new question if you do.

Comment: if u help me with finding those array element have contain 'ent', 'net', 'ten' with also those words that have single or double charcter before or after it i.e., 'sten' , 'netff' etc then i have no issue

Comment: Getting your question re-opened is probably going to take a while.  Perhaps ask a new question with different criteria (not requiring regex) to filter your `$findgroup` array.

Comment: If u find any solution plz let me know. I am stuck on that issue for long time

Comment: I'm telling you I have a working solution.  I spent about an hour thinking/developing/testing it, so I kind of what to get some points out of it.  If you start up a new question, I'll answer it while I am still awake.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916223/find-element-of-an-array-those-contains-only-specific-character-set-in-php)

check this one plz