# Find element of an array those contains only specific character set in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, substring, filtering

I need to find only the elements of an array that have a specific set of letters and any character before or after the set of letters.

I have arrays like these:

```
$sample = array("sten", "netff", "enet", "denet");

$value = array('e', 'n', 't');
```

I need to find the values from the `$sample` array which have `'e,n,t'` characters and single or double character before or after(either side, not both side) the match word. If I search with pattern e,n,t and 1 letter before or after(either side, not both side) it, the result will be

```
array("sten", "enet")
```

and if I search with pattern e,n,t and 2 letter before or after(either side, not both side) it, the result will be

```
array("netff", "denet")
```

I tried regex with `preg_grep()` but it doesn't work:

1 letter before or after(either side, not both side):

```
$result = preg_grep("/^(?:.{1}".$value."|".$value.".{1})$/", $sample);
```

2 letter before or after(either side, not both side):

```
$result = preg_grep("/^(?:.{2}".$value."|".$value.".{2})$/", $sample);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you have already pre-filtered all strings to be either 4 or 5 characters long -- if not, you can uncomment my first filter function.

Inputs:

```
$findgroup=['eaten','enter','tend','sten','neat','dents','enet','netty','teeth','denet','teen','spent'];
$values=['e','n','t'];
```

Method:

```
//$findgroup=array_filter($findgroup,function($v){return strlen($v)==4 || strlen($v)==5;});
$findgroup=array_filter($findgroup,function($v)use($values){
    return
        sizeof(array_intersect(array_unique(str_split(substr($v,0,3))),$values))==3 ||
        sizeof(array_intersect(array_unique(str_split(substr($v,-3))),$values))==3;
});
var_export($findgroup);    
// omitted: neat, dents, teeth, teen
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'eaten',
  1 => 'enter',
  2 => 'tend',
  3 => 'sten',
  6 => 'enet',
  7 => 'netty',
  9 => 'denet',
  11 => 'spent',
)
```

Comment: @VaswatiPal Your question appears to be unresolved.  How close did I get to solving your question?  Do I need to adjust my answer?